# Custom image cropper android

Tags: android, image, imageview, crop, shapes

I need to crop an image that I take from the gallery in some custom shapes (like heart, star, ..) but I have not found any android library that does this.

A very good library is this https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView
where i can put a svg file of my shape, but I can't crop the image because that is a simple ImageView.

There is any library that does this? How could I solve this?

**EDIT #1:**

I'm trying all the ways to do this.. but now I need to know if there is a way to convert svg file or bitmap file to android "Path" variable

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

add on 
dependencies

```
{ compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
}
```

And to apply any shape:

```
    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.HexagonImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_imageview"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"

            android:background="@color/transparent"
 />
```

Comment: The problem is that I want move and save the cropped image with the shape that I have decided

Comment: So organize your question.

Comment: Hello you know how to make heart shape cropview in android.